Enter multiple objects within a record in a mysql table
I have a local website with php and mysql of products, purchases, sales, customers and suppliers, but every product I sell or buy must go in a mysql registry. That's how I've always done it and I hadn't had any problems. But now I realize that every time a purchase or sale is made, with an invoice for example, several products are usually included in it.
On the web I already know how I would implement it, but how can I do it in my mysql database? Every time you register a purchase or a sale would it be an enum of products? I don't know where to start modifying my database and I need to finish the work before the summer for a client. If you could help me, I would appreciate it. If you need any sample code, I can place it here.

I usually do it like this - one table for the orders, and the other for the orderdetails. In the details, you'd have a FK for order_id, and that would be your connection to the orders table. The orders table would have its own id, buyer's id, date of purchase, status (processing, complete, refunded, etc), perhaps a soft delete column, and so on. The orderdetails would hold specific items with their quantities, unit prices, discounts / rebates, etc. Perhaps this would work for you.

Always provide your sample code so community can see what you have tried so far.

Create a table, if you don't have one, where you save the purchased products. Then you will have the table of purchased Products and the table of purchase details.
Now in your PHP code iterate over each purchased product and insert them into your purchased products table:
foreach ($purchasedProducts as $product) {
      $productId = $product['id'];
      $quantity = $product['quantity'];
      $price = $product['price'];

// SQL query 
$sql = "INSERT INTO purchased_products (purchase_id, product_id, quantity, price) 
        VALUES (:purchaseId, :productId, :quantity, :price)";

